# magento status Use Default Value for all products

Tags: magento-1.8, product, attributes, status

I did a bulk action, to enable and disable all products for a storeview in my product overview.

But now all the products are not using the default value anymore for status.
Is there way to check the "Use Default Value" back again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty way.
Identify the `status` attribute id.

```
SELECT 
    attribute_id
FROM 
    eav_attribute
WHERE
    attribute_code = 'status' AND 
    entity_type_id = (SELECT 
                entity_type_id 
              FROM 
                eav_entity_type
              WHERE
                entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
            )
```

with the value you get from the above query run this (I got 273):

```
DELETE FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE 
    attribute_id = 273 AND
    store_id <> 0
```

This will delete the records for status attribute for all other store views except the default values.

Make sure you reindex when you are done.
And back up the db before trying it.

Comment: I don't have catalog_product_int, do you mean catalog_product_entity?

Comment: @Royw. Sorry. it should be `catalog_product_entity_int`. I fixed it

Comment: Thnx, it works!

Comment: Hi from the future! 2023 doesn't seem to have an use_default for `status` in the API Call - so seemingly this appears to be the only way to update status on-masse for multi-store views. Thanks @Marius